# How to construct the url attribute in Backbone.Model and Backbone.Collection?

Tags: backbone.js

Currently I'm doing a local Backbone app. And I want to know how to save data, specifically, how to construct the `url` attribute for Collection and Model. I have created a folder called data which is intended to hold the data. But how is the data structured? Is it just a single json file to hold the whole Collection data in it? Or it has many seprate json files to hold each Model's data individually? If it's a single json file, how should I created the `url` atrributes for both Collection and Model? If they are many separate json files, What should I do?

Comment: It is not clear as to what you want to know from asking `how is the data structured?` but i will take a shot at the answer

Comment: @Deeptechtons I just want to know how to construct the `url` attribute for Model and Collection.

Comment: I suggest to have look at this link, which has complete app created with backbone. http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/employee-directory-sample-app-with-backbone-js-and-jquery-mobile/

Comment: @Jaydeep I viewed this app before but actually all it uses is just static data, which means all you can do is just search, you can not modify the item or create new item. So it doesn't involve in any updating or creating data activities.

Answer (score 0):

It is upto you :) . Backbone.Js `models`, `collections` work and can be made to work with pretty much any type of data source that **expose through HTTP and URL**. But it was designed to work against REST based services out of the box. Since you are interested to test the library and learning it i will advice you to stick to static JSON file or even Twitter timeline service.

- Since all collections are in single JSOn file you will need just to set the URl for the collection.
- View that renders the collection will instantiate the models and render them from the collection

#### Application

```
window["Application"] = {};

Application.Model = {};
Application.Collection = {};
Application.Views = {};
Application.Templates = {};
Application.Router = {};
```

#### Collection from url

```
Application.Collection.TimeLine = Backbone.Collection.extend({
url:"data/collection.json"
});
```

Current Url is `http://localhost/timelineapp/index.html`

Collection.Fetch will make GET request to `http://localhost/timelineapp/data/collection.json`

is this not clear enough i will add more detail

Comment: So in your example, I don't need to set the url attribute in my Model. and every time the model get updated, created or deleted, I just use `this.model.save()` in my Model and the data will get updated automatically?

Comment: OK.Let's do it. But how to make a chat?

Comment: Please continue the chat from here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10697/discussion-between-chaonextdoor-and-deeptechtons-on-backbone-js

Comment: I'm in the room now. But it seems that you are not there.

Comment: @chaonextdoor I am in now, hope you are available too :)